# Aggregating two 4G/3G data links from 2 different sims?

Tags: mobile-network, 3g, 4g, dual-sim, carriers

Having two 4G capable sims -from truely two different operators (no virtual carriers at all)- and a Dual Active sim phone (Zenfone 2 Laser), I want to do true load balancing with a 1 sim + 1 sim 4G/3G data links configuration.

However, all I can find when googling is about Dual-Carrier -or Dual-Band (HSDPA++, LTE)-, which is clearly not what I'm trying to do since it's just combining two same operator frequencies to boost speeds.

The approach is like the "speedify" tool, but instead of mixing 4G and WiFi, I only want to mix the 3G/4G sims.

So, the question is: Do someone know how to achieve that on Android ?

By the way, is this automatically managed in Android, or is it driver/kernel/modem (e.g. Qualcomm X10, X12 hardware/firmware, etc) dependant or do I have to enable something manually ?

Any information about that is ok too :)

If possible, the best scenario would be having twice the Dual-Band enabled. This means a Dual Carrier + Dual Carrier configuration, for a total of 4 bands from two totally different operators.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this setup? Enhanced download speeds? I can't say for sure, but I would assume Android was never build for load sharing between SIMs, only that is allows you to choose an active one, but I've never owned a dual-sim. Can you get a phone call from both numbers simultaneously?

Comment: I'm trying to get better coverage and speed in massively crowded situations, where I often got Denial of Service and can't work at all. You can have two sims working at the same time (call, data, etc), which is Dual Active Sims; or have only one active sim when activity (call, 4G on one of the two sims, etc) is detected by the phone, which is Dual Stand-By Sims. I have a Dual Active sims phone, but I feel that the two sims aren't aggregated since I don't see the two data links working at the same time for the same task (or it looks like it isn't).

Comment: I would bet that it would require some serious packet management to loadbalance between two separate chips - not a feature that would warrant being made for a mid-tier mobile device.

Comment: You may be right, but do you know if it has already been done in the past by software means ? (custom ROM, custom kernel, "speedify Dual Active sims only", etc)

Comment: Dual Active Sim is a pretty niche market. I do not know.

Comment: You have to choose the sim  for data in the settings so you can not access both sim's data at a time

Comment: `Dual Active Sim is a pretty niche market. I do not know` there are markets where it is very popular and I disagree that it is niche

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, the modem only exist one 4G.
You can use it in both SIM (switch it) but you can't use both at the same time.
Even if you're thinking using the first one is 4G and the last one is 3G, it won't work. It's dual-band not dual channel, and beside it will make your phone a lot thirstier than before and i'm pretty sure you don't want that.